# Using Isopropyl alcohol to clean SSD, CPU/GPU sockets

Tags: ssd, cpu, gpu, cleaning, water-damage

Wanted to ask after reading [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/598468/how-do-i-clean-my-computer-using-isopropyl-alcohol#639721).

there are visible signs of moisture on or bear components of a laptop after the machine was exposed to steam/water vapor and you are [concerned about corrosion even if you manage to dry the component](https://darwinsdata.com/is-putting-electronics-in-rice-good/).

1. Suppose some of the surface mount components on a board have visible signs of moisture, is it safe to try to get Isopropyl Alchohol (IPA) between the IC and the board to clean the contacts to prevent corrosion (without removing it, just trying to "drip" it in there)? For example, IC's on an SSD, or the storage module itself
2. the machine is a laptop and there are visibile moisture A: near B: on, the CPU/GPU, would it be safe to clean the CPU/GPU pins/socket with IPA?

*Is it safe to use IPA in these ways?/would doing so damage the components?*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149921/discussion-on-question-by-the-floating-brain-using-isopropyl-alcohol-to-clean-ss); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wind is your best friend. Get some airflow to the component before, while and after the application of IPA.

[image: Rubber air pump dust blower]

Even better if you can get compressed air easily. In simple cases, even a table fan would do.
You will need some kind of air direction manipulation (like the above air pump) in case of dust in close gaps, though. **Do not** *blow* it with your mouth, unless you are some organism that doesn't create saliva (or humid breath).

1. To determine whether you need to use IPA to clean the component

   1. clean as much of the dust you can with wind.
   2. use a dry microfiber cloth (the kind that you might get free with monitor screens) to clean wherever you can reach
   3. Use a paint brush (without the paint of course) for harder to reach places
   4. Inspect the resultant object under a light from different angles

      - You want to look for gunk at the contacts (those may create undesirable electrical tunnels, but mostly tend to be not conducting enough). Other places won't really be as much of a problem.
      - Worst offenders are tar from cigarettes. That's also the hardest to remove and will stick to everything you try to clean with.
      - Heat sink locations are another good place to look for, which you would want to clean.
2. To determine whether you can use IPA - If the component has some kind of conformal coating (SSDs and hot components usually don't), you can be more liberal with IPA. The contacts tend to have some openings, so evaporation is still necessary.
3. How to use IPA

   1. Use it [like you would use water](https://superuser.com/questions/598468/how-do-i-clean-my-computer-using-isopropyl-alcohol#comment797748_598475). Dampen the cloth a bit and rub it on the place you want to clean. Remember, you are not applying IPA, you are cleaning the component and taking the help of IPA to dampen the gunk.
   2. As mentioned before, airflow is important.

      - If there seems to be a gap in between the component and the PCB, try flowing air along the edge towards the corner, to make sure the small amount of IPA that might go in, flows outward as it evaporates.
   3. If you can see a drop forming on the component (even in the gaps), you are using too much.

[You might want to check the purity of your IPA.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27130/testing-isopropyl-alcohol-purity) I find it easiest to simply sandwich a drop between 2 plates (no pressure on the plates) and check how long it takes for all of it to evaporate. This gives an idea of how and where-all I can use it.

---

In case the component was already exposed to steam and has moisture still sitting on it (and in between components), I would go with giving the water droplets as much energy to leave the surface as possible.

- Go with a few sprays of 99.9% IPA (at least what is advertised) with high airflow at around 30°C to 40°C
- End it with a dry cloth

Comment: @Ulterno Thanks for the answer! What about trying to get some IPA between a surface mount component (without removing it), and the board in order to prevent corrosion on the contacts?

Comment: “What about trying to get some IPA between a surface mount component…” Who cares? They are most likely clean and fine. What is this concern about? You will only break things if you “clean” things that are not dirty.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 If there are visible sigbs of moisture on/near the components that seems like cause for concern about thins like corrosion even if you dry the components

Comment: Do you think asking the same ridiculous question over and over and over and over and again in slightly different forms will result in a different answer? You have your answer from multiple community members in the comments and an answer.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 You asked "who cares", and said "its most likely clean and fine" and in other places have been asking me why it matters too me. Perhapse you are right that my comment before my previous one should be phrased asking for clarification (as Im not entierly sure if Ulterno means to include cleaning between the board and a component when they said "between components" towards the end of their answer). Though I think I phrased it that way because I hadent edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: @Ulterno, I appreciate your answer, and it is helpful. If you clarify about trying to get IPA between an SMD and the board, I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain As I mentioned in 3.2. even if you use IPA in the space between the component and the PCB, you definitely want to get rid of it before actually using it. That's where the compressed air comes in.

Whenever I mention "between components", I mean the gap between separate components on the PCB which may be close to each other. I have specially mentioned the space between component and PCB in 3.2. where I mean it.
The the "wide net" answer was because similar concepts apply to all parts of cleaning electronics and associate well when grouped together.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain on the other hand, if your question pertains to applying and keeping the IPA in that gap, that will have different answers, which I can't answer due to not actually having tried it and not having any handed down knowledge regarding so either.
I have however gotten rid of corrosion between closely situated pins of a QFP component using IPA and earbuds, but I made sure to remove the IPA by blowing air (I just kept a duct fan nearby for 10 minutes) before using it

Comment: @Ulterno Sounds good, thank you for clarifying, marking as answer! Thanks for your help!